# UI Validation before executing RelayCommand WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I'm new to WPF and I tried to implement a demo application with [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051).

My question is this:

If i want to execute a command which has to ask the user if he's sure he wants to execute it first - what's the best way to do it?
I need an "are you sure?" messagebox to pop. However, the command is executed on the viewmodel, and of course I don't want to mess with GUI there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this myself.  I'm using MVVM Light, and I used the Messenger to accomplish this.

I had my ViewModel send a `GetConfirmationMessage`, which I had registered in the code-behind.  Within the handler for `GetConfirmationMessage`, I popped up the dialog box and got the reuslts. If the user clicked on OK, I then sent a `ConfirmationReceived` message, which was handled by the ViewModel to do the appropriate updates.

Answer (score 2):

The way I deal with this is to have an `IDialogService` interface that is registered in your IOC and available to your ViewModels.

The service then provides various ways of interacting with the "user". So you could have a ConfirmMessage method, that returns true or false based on the user accepting a dialog.

Then for unit testing say, you can have a different `IDialogService` implementation that allows you to feed canned responses to your ViewModel when under test.